# Capistrano - Previewing deploy and manually update symlink

Tags: magento, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I am using a Capistrano deployment workflow for a Magento project.

On deploy Capistrano builds this Magento project on the server using https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer.

The issue is sometimes my Magento modules don't install correctly and I need to clear the cache, reindex or some other task to get everything 100%. The issues occur sporadically so I haven't been able to script a fix into the deployment process.

What I would like is on deploy Capistrano does not change the symlink to the new build straight away. Instead I am able to preview the site on another link, fix what needs to be fixed, then change the symlink manually.

Is this possible to set up using Capistrano?

If not, my other solution to this is to use the Magento maintenance flag however I would rather avoid having to put the site in maintenance. Open to other idea's as well!

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: My question is intended to be Capistrano related which is a remote server automation tool that supports scripting and in my opinion comes under the banner of "software tools commonly used by programmers". Magento was used as my example however the question could relate to anyone using Capistrano. I will try magento.stackexchange nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably possible to do this by telling Capistrano to not include the symlink change as part of the process (something like `Rake::Task["deploy:symlink:release"].clear_actions`), and then running that manually (`cap [env] deploy:symlink:release`).

However, under the category of "Open to other ideas as well!" I'd suggest that you set up a staging site. Create a process to automatically restore a prod database back to stage, then deploy your code to stage and check it there. Once you have confirmed it works, deploy to prod and let the symlinks automatically do their job.